# How do I return the key of an appengine datastore object from the template in index.html?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, post, request

I want my users to be able to modify the attributes of displayed datastore objects by clicking buttons next to each object.

In order to do this, I believe I need to get the id of the datastore object back from index.html when the user clicks the button:

from index.html:

```
{% for polyhedron in polyhedrons %}
    {{ polyhedron.name }}
    {{ polyhedron.color }} 
    <form action="/correction" method=post>
        <input type=submit id="{{ polyhedron.key }}" name=content value="red">
        <input type=submit id="{{ polyhedron.key }}" name=content value="green">
    </form>
```

the handler:

```
class CorrectionHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        polyhedron_object = self.request.get("id")
        polyhedron_object.color = self.request.get('content')
```

However, self.request.get("id") returns nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a hidden input for the object's ID. I'm not sure if you are using [db.Model](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass) or [ndb.Model](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass). If you are using db.Model for your objects, I would do:

```
{% for polyhedron in polyhedrons %}
{{ polyhedron.name }}
{{ polyhedron.color }} 
<form action="/correction" method=post>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ polyhedron.key().id() }}">
    <input type="submit" id="{{ polyhedron.key().id() }}" name="color" value="red">
    <input type="submit" id="{{ polyhedron.key().id() }}" name="color" value="green">
</form>
```

If you are using ndb.Model, I would do

```
{% for polyhedron in polyhedrons %}
{{ polyhedron.name }}
{{ polyhedron.color }} 
<form action="/correction" method=post>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ polyhedron.key.urlsafe() }}">
    <input type="submit" id="{{ polyhedron.key.urlsafe() }}" name="color" value="red">
    <input type="submit" id="{{ polyhedron.key.urlsafe() }}" name="color" value="green">
</form>
```

Your handler if you are using db.Model is:

```
class CorrectionHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        polyhedron_object_key = self.request.get("key")
        polyhedron_object = Polyhedron.get_by_id(polyhedron_object_key)
        polyhedron_object.color = self.request.get('color')
```

Your handler if you are using ndb.Model is:

```
class CorrectionHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        polyhedron_object_key = self.request.get("key")
        polyhedron_object = ndb.Key(urlsafe=polyhedron_object_key).get()
        polyhedron_object.color = self.request.get('color')
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using db. Your answer brought me, I think, very close to a solution, but I get an error on the get_by_id(): "BadArgumentError: Expected an instance or iterable of (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>); received 165 (a unicode)." If I cast the id to int or long, I get a 'None' object. In other words, I don't know how to ensure that the id has the right type when returned.

Comment: Casting to integer shouldn't return None. Are you doing the following:   polyhedron_object = Polyhedron.get_by_id(int(polyhedron_object_key))

Comment: Change `polyhedron.key().id()` with `polyhedron.key.id` and the above may work.  Note that parenthesis are not allowed in Django template variables.

Comment: @AaronHampton Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing, with Polyhedron being the entity class. The object is displayed on the web page without problems, and it has attributes that I can access when returning it to the handler, but somehow, the obect itself becomes 'None' when I try to retreive it from db with the key cast to int.

Comment: @Kekito I'm using jinja2, and as far as I can see, it works better with the parens.

Comment: @AaronHampton It seems to me as if everything that comes back from the template is a unicode string. Is that right? And, if so, is it possible to change it, so that I can return a Key object?

Comment: You can't have it return a Key object from the html template. Can you confirm that an object exists with the ID you have? It looks like the object with that ID is not being found. Does your object have a parent key?

Comment: My objects did have parent keys. As a result of your question, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072939/get-by-id-will-not-return-model-instance).

I removed the parent relationship, and now the object returned is printed not as 'None', but as nothing at all. Even so, I'm able to access all its attributes, and update its color, so I consider the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think polyhedron.key containts something like Key('Polyhedron', 1). To get only object ID try this:

```
{% for polyhedron in polyhedrons %}
    {{ polyhedron.name }}
    {{ polyhedron.color }} 
    <form action="/correction" method=post>
        <input type=submit id="{{ polyhedron.key.id() }}" name=content value="red">
        <input type=submit id="{{ polyhedron.key.id() }}" name=content value="green">
    </form>
```

And then in your handler build key again:

```
class CorrectionHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        polyhedron_object = self.request.get("id")
        polyhedron__key = ndb.Key('Polyhedron', self.request.get('id'))
        polyhedron_object.color = self.request.get('content')
```

Where Polyhedron is your model name.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your HTML attributes.  When you do:

```
self.request.get("foo")
```

it returns the value of the HTML element that has "foo" as the "name".  So change your HTML to this:

```
<form action="/correction" method=post>
    <input type=submit name="{{ polyhedron.key.id }}" value="red">
    <input type=submit name="{{ polyhedron.key.id }}" value="green">
</form>
```

and then

```
self.request.get("123")
```

will return the color for the id that is 123.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple if you are using db.model

First of all, you don't request for the value using the id of the input tag, you use the name rather.

Secondly, just as Aaron mentioned, your users don't need to see that key. Keep it hidden

So your html should look like this

```
{% for polyhedron in polyhedrons %}
    {{ polyhedron.name }}
    {{ polyhedron.color }} 
   <form action="/correction" method=post>
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{polyhedron.key()}}">
        <input type="submit" id="{{ polyhedron.key().id() }}" name="color" value="red">
        <input type="submit" id="{{ polyhedron.key().id() }}" name="color" value="green">
   </form>
```

And finally your handler should look like this

```
class CorrectionHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        color = self.request.get("color")
        polyhedron_key = self.request.get("key")
        polyhedron_object = db.get(polyhedron_key)

        if color == "red":
            polyhedron_object.color = "red"
        else:
            polyhedron_object.color = "green"
        polyhedron_object.put()
```

As you can see I used some python code in there but you can follow the same logic if you are using Java. I hope it was helpful